# How to rename a modem device in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, modem, device-manager

I've just connected a Bluetooth mobile phone to my Vista laptop.

The modem has been beautifully named: "Standard Modem over Bluetooth link #3".

What do I do, short of editing the registry, to rename the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In registry, you can do this, but **I don't recommending do this**, because this change has many bad consequences.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> Enum

And here is list of devices in categories. Each device has DeviceInstanceID.

Name is under DriverDesc or FriendlyName and you can change.

Comment: I know how to do it using the registry. I was hoping for a way to do it without.

Comment: I suppose there is no other way.